# How to change <a> href when I chose a <select> option in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to create a connection betwen a  and  that if I selected some VALUE the href of the  will change, is it possible in JavaScript?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><select id="worldsize">
                           <option value="small_world" selected="">Small</option>
                           <option value="normal_world">Normal</option>
                           <option value="huge_world">Huge</option>
                           <option value="infinte_world" disabled="">Infinite</option>
                        </select>
<a name="a "class="for_a_button CreateANewWorldButton Checkout" href="?START_S" id="button_click">Create an new World</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add onchange handler to select tag and access a tag via document.getelmentById('button_click')     <select onchange="change()">  function change() { document.getElementById('buton_click').innerHTML ="something"}

Comment: Yes this is easily achievable.  What have you tried so far to do it?

Comment: intercept the `change` event of a `select` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: The classic event to listen to is `onchange`. However, a more modern approach is `oninput`, which unifies several event interfaces under one single umbrella and greatly simplifies the loops and hoops through which a developer needs to go in order to bind a particular routine to a form element's value being changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><select id="worldsize" onchange="change(this.value)">
                           <option value="small_world" selected="">Small</option>
                           <option value="normal_world">Normal</option>
                           <option value="huge_world">Huge</option>
                           <option value="infinte_world" disabled="">Infinite</option>
                        </select>
<a name="a "class="for_a_button CreateANewWorldButton Checkout" href="?START_S" id="button_click">Create an new World</a>


<script>

function change(val){
  document.getElementById("button_click").href= val;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add onchange() function for select tag